# High-resolution, hyperspectral satellite imaging?

Tags: satellite, resolution, hyperspectral-sensor, biology

I am hoping to expand my (biology-focused) research to include satellite data. For this, I'd need satellite imaging that includes multiple values in the visible spectrum (specifically, above 490nm) and extends slightly into the infrared (710nm). I have tried MERIS and Hyperion, but the resolution was insufficient (my area of interest is a lake ~300m x 55m). Does anything like this exist, and is it freely available for research use?

Comment: I would also try asking on the Open Data Stack Exchange. You may have luck  there.

Comment: Didn't say where specific area are you looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider [WorldView 2 or 3](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/worldview-2.htm), with 0.5 m spatial resolution and including red-edge and near-infrared bands. However, Worldview images are proprietary data from Digital Globe and must be purchased.

Comment: Thank you. The spectral bands of Worldview seem too wide for my calculations (ideally I'd prefer measurements at known wavelengths rather than a range). Would you happen to have any other suggestions?

Comment: Indeed, WV3 spectral bands are rather wide compared to true hyperspectral imagers. I believe no true hyperspectral instruments (with ~5 nm spectral band width) are currently carried on a satellite. There are some airplane-carried hyperspectral sensors though, such as [APEX](http://apex.vgt.vito.be/) sensor, or [AVIRIS](https://aviris.jpl.nasa.gov/).

Answer (score -1):

What about Sentinels of European Commission. We use the to identifie time of harvest, areas of snow, fire... Resolution is 10×10 meters. They take pistures in 9 spectrums.

https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home

Just neet to register and you got all data series fro couple of years. And most important, everthing is free.

Comment: Sentinel-2 is neither high-resolution or hyper-spectral.